# Задача на Stream API Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Необходимо создать класс **клиента** со следующими полями:
*уникальный идентификатор*, *имя*, *возраст*. Также у клиента есть *список телефонов*. Класс **телефона** содержит само *значение* и *тип* (стационарный или мобильный).

Найти самого возрастного клиента, которой пользуется стационарным телефоном

```
 static class Client {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Integer age;
    List<Phone> phones;
    ...
 }

 static class Phone {
    Long number;
    PhoneType type;
    ...

    enum PhoneType {
        STATIONARY,
        MOBIL
    }
 }

 clients.stream()...
```

Как отфильтровать клиентов по полю вложенного списка (тип телефона) и сохранить клиента в потоке для дальнейшего поиска максимального возраста?

Comment: Добавил ещё несколько комментариев в ответ, чтобы было понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать тот же самый SteamAPI.

```
// Искомый тип телефона.
Phone.PhoneType searchableType = Phone.PhoneType.STATIONARY;

Client oldestClient = clients.stream()
    // Оставляет пользователей, у которых в результате метода "filter" вернулось "true".
    .filter((client) -> 
        // Проверяет, имеется ли в списке телефонов телефон с искомым типом.
        client.phones.stream()
            .anyMatch((phone) -> phone.type == searchableType)
    )
    // Находит клиента с самым большим возрастом.
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(client -> client.age))
    // Так как функция "max" возвращает "Optional", добавляем "orElse", который вернёт default значение ( в нашем случае null ), если после "filter" клиентов не осталось ( ничего не найдено ).
    .orElse(null);
```